# Print using the System.Printing objects

Tags: .net, printing

I'm trying to print using the `System.Printing` namepace's objects.

I've got the following:

```
public static void Print()
{
    var local = new LocalPrintServer();
    var printQueue = local.GetPrintQueue("Microsoft Print to PDF");
    var defaultPrintTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;
    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"Printing @ {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");

    using (var job = printQueue.AddJob("Dave", defaultPrintTicket))
    {
        job.JobStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        job.Commit();
    }
}
```

However, when the code gets to the `Commit` method I get a `NotSupportedException` without any other information.

I have expected the code to present me with the save as PDF dialogue box and produce a PDF with `Printing @ {the current time}` as it does using `PrintDocument`:

```
public static void Print()
{
    using (var printDocument = new PrintDocument())
    {
        printDocument.DocumentName = "Dave's Document";

        printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            var fontFamily = FontFamily.GenericMonospace;
            var size = 12;
            var graphics = eventArgs.Graphics;
            var font = new Font(fontFamily, size);
            var brush = Brushes.Black;
            graphics.RenderingOrigin = new Point(100, 100);
            graphics.DrawString($"Printing @ {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}", font, brush, new PointF(200, 20), new StringFormat());
        };

        printDocument.Print();
    }
}
```

---

NB:  I can print using the `PrintDocument` object in the `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace.

Comment: This code does not make any sense, you'll have to describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @HansPassant Not making any sense might explain why it doesn't work.  I've added a working example.